# LDAP configuration: slap_init no backend for

Tags: server, ldap

like my tag is suggesting I have a problem with my ubuntu server where 16.04 LTS is running. I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps. The output after the configuration is the following:

```
Creating initial configuration... done.
  Creating LDAP directory... failed.
Loading the initial configuration from the ldif file () failed with
the following error while running slapadd:
    slapadd: slap_init no backend for "dc=MYDOMAIN,dc=de"
```

I have no clue where to find logs because in `/etc/logs/` there is not ldap folder, I am just a beginner so please be gentle.

Thx for your efforts.
SchoolGuy

EDIT: In addition to this failure I found another more specific message when typing: `ldapsearch -d 1 -v -H ldap://mydomain:389`

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
    additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate)
```

`ldapsearch -x` just gives the error `ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconfigured slapd after a hundred of reinstalations, now it runns smoth as nothing else in this universe like nothing was ever wrong... Hope I can edit this answer in the future and provide you with an answer.

SchoolGuy